# Is there a number limit on opened win32 IStream object for IStorage created with StgCreateStorageEx?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, window, ole

I create an IStorage by `StgCreateStorageEx` function, with type: `STGFMT_STORAGE`.

Then I used the `CreateStream` method to create `IStream` objects (around 60).

I didn't call `Release` on all of the `IStream` interfaces, but when I call `Seek` on some of them, it returns `STG_E_REVERTED`.

However, if I create them and use them one by one, it works properly.

Does anyone know why?

Is there a limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380020%28VS.85%29.aspx) says:

- The `STGM_DELETEONRELEASE` flag is not supported.
- Opening the same stream more than once from the same storage is not supported. The `STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE` sharing-mode flag must be specified in the `grfMode` parameter.

Did you release these streams before?

Comment: yar, I didn't open the same stream twice, I open 60 different streams

Comment: @xijing dai: Had you used them before, so did you release these streams before?

Comment: here is logic:

I create a map to store the filename and the IStream*, after I created them, i cache them. later on, when i access them, some of Istream* return STG_E_REVERTED error msg. For sure, it will keep 1 count at least(I also checked, it didn't reach 0). Do you have any idea y it happened?

Answer (score 0):

I expect tha this will depend on the maximum nr of filehandles openend allowed by the OS. For the windows case see this discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/ce6ce7df-b769-41b7-bccf-b75707c0a729/

Comment: In that case, why do I have invalid IStream to be seeked?
I suppose if I don't call Release on IStream, it should always be valid, isn't it?